# Issues with using "self" to access parent methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Within Python, I can define two classes `parent` and `child`, where the child class inherits from the parent class. Then within `child` I can use `self` and can access any methods that exist in the parent class (and presumably any other parent class in the inheritance tree) as long as the name has not been overridden in the child class.

Are there caveats to doing this? And is the recommended method just to use `super()`?

Code Example:

```
class parent:
    def add_stars(self, str):
        return '***'+str+'***'

class child(parent):
    def print_something(self):
        print(self.add_stars("Bacon"))

[In Console]
>>> c = child()
>>> c.add_stars("Wow")
'***Wow***'
>>> c.print_something()
'***Bacon***'
```

**Edit:** Going to add more clarity based on the discussion in the comments for anyone that comes across this later. What confused me was that another way of writing the above `child` class & getting the same functionality was to use `super()`:

```
class child(parent):
    def print_something(self):
        print(super().add_stars("Bacon"))
```

This is the same as long as `child` doesn't define a method called `add_stars` as well. If that method does exist in `child`, then `self` will instead use the method defined in the `child` class, whereas `super()` will skip the `child` class and only look in superclasses. Additionally, both will use the same Method Resolution Order. What I wanted to know was, are there any issues with using `self` as I did in the example, when would you typically use `super` instead, etc?

This was answered below and in the comments.

Comment: This is the whole point of inheritance - you don't need `callPrinty`, a consumer of your classes can just *call `printy`* on any instance of `parent` or any of its children. If you need to override it in any of the children, you can. If the parent implementation also needs to be invoked, you can use `super`.

Comment: Hi Jon. Yep, I understand that aspect of it; tried to make that seem clear in the part of the code where I wrote c.printy() and showed the output. In the instance where a subclass needs/wants to call a parent class method as a part of another method however, it seems there are several ways to achieve this. I don't think I've seen any examples where using "self" to call a parent method is used over say super(), so I wanted to know what the drawbacks were to this approach. I might edit the post to add a more realistic requirement to the example, but didn't want to overdo it.

Comment: `self.method` is used where the child *doesn't* override that method, `super().method` is used when it does, but you need to *explicitly* bypass the override (e.g. because that's the method you're in and you don't want to cause endless recursion). I don't know what you mean by *"drawbacks"*.

Comment: Well, for instance, if you know you're extending or accessing a method that's only defined in a specific superclass, using `super` over `self` is probably a bit more readable. Additionally `super` can be used to directly select which superclass method you want to access in the event of multiple-inheritance where the method name occurs more than once (assuming 'self' will just use the one that's defined first). I.e. `child(p1, p2):` `def something(self): self.method()` would use `p1.method` over `p2.method` correct? But are there any other "gotchas" / bad in practice for not using super?

Comment: *"extending or accessing"* are two very different cases. The point of super is that you **don't** have to *"directly select which superclass"*; if `child` doesn't override `method` then again `self.method` is fine.

Comment: Ok. I think this has more or less answered my question. Is there then no fundamental difference then between writing: `self.add_stars("Bacon")` and `super().add_stars("Bacon")` if there is no method named `add_stars` in the child class? Also, fiddled a bit in the console, sorry I thought you could specify the method resolution order via `super()` but that doesn't seem to be the case; that was part of my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to think of `super` is pretend it was actually called `next`, as in "next in the method resolution order". In this *particular case*, there is no difference. Using `self.some_method` will try to resolve "some_method" in the current class namespace, not find it, go to the *next* class in the MRO, check there, find it, and it will be resolved.

If you added super, it *skips* the current class namespace.

In general, it is not true that the two would be equivalent. You shouldn't use `super` unless that is actually what you are trying to do, even in the cases where it is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there caveats to doing this?

No, your code is fine, it correctly calls the parent function.

The current code has no need of `super()`.
If your classes had constructors, the child constructor would have to make a call to `super()`.

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you name the classes `Parent` and `Child`, with initial capital.

You would benefit from `pip install flake8` and following the advice it offers when you run `flake8 *.py`.